# How to know if a button is clicked before another one?

Tags: java, algorithm

If we have two buttons and we want to know which one is clicked before the other how can we do that in java?

**Scenario:** ButtonA and ButtonB , ButtonB clicked before ButtonA Clicked.

How can we determine that pragmatically?(I mean the order button clicked)

Comment: Set a variable of some type which maintains information which button was pressed.  You could also use some kind FIFO queue.  But without actually coding for it, there is no other 100% sure way

Comment: but I want to know the order , I know you speak about boolean but I can't really find a solution to that

Comment: Without any code to go on, this question is too broad for SO. Any answer would have to be so vague as to not really be helpful (as has just happened). You should try *something*, and post a specific question if there's a part of the code that you wrote which isn't working as you expect.

Comment: Please post the code what you have already done, at least the methods with button click methods and what should be the output. Do you need any event triggered after two buttons clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume for a moment, you have the source code and you're trying to introduce this into your own program, then I would recommend using some kind of FIFO queue.

Each time one of these buttons is pressed, you pop it onto the queue.  When you need to determine the order, you simply pop off the items and they will come out in order.

Have a look at [Queue Implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html) and [Introduction to Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html) for more details

Now, having said that, you could simply use a `List`, this will maintain an order of items (from first to last), but will allow duplicates, so you could up with `[B1, B1, B1, B2, B1]` for example.

If you want uniqueness (no duplicates) then some kind of `Set` would be more useful

Comment: I understand now really thank you , I have a small question is there a way to learn progrmamation tips and solution or we learn this by programming ? (sorry if question is out of subject you can ignore if you want) and really thank you !

Comment: Experience is gained a lot by doing something, but one of the most powerful tools in your arsenal is the ability to research a problem.  99% of the problems you will encounter have already been encountered by others and they've either asked the question of others or answered it themselves. The willingness to self learn is also very important. Don't be afraid to read blogs, tutorials and forums just because you can. Don't be afraid to re-try problems you've had in the past with new ideas you might have learned or developed ... and if you get really stuck, ask...